# CSS Navigation Menu Custom symbol

Tags: css

I am trying to figure how the "plus" symbol is being shown on the navigation menu item's hover event on this page : http://www.syracusecoe.org/coe/

Can anyone please give some suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion is to learn how to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or a similar tool so you can figure out these things by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is added as a background image... <s>You can find the styles here</s>

http://www.syracusecoe.org/coe/SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarVertical.css

At line 175.

Heres the code since it might be hard to find line 175 in a browser.

```
/* Menu items that are open with submenus have the class designation MenuBarItemSubmenuHover and are set to use a "hover" background image positioned on the far left (95%) and centered vertically (50%) */
ul.MenuBarVertical a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover
{
    background-image: url(../switchimages//wh_cross.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}
```

Oh and that is a class that is added using javascript, it's not a css :hover that does this.

Answer (score 0):

The hover state adds a background image using CSS.

Comment: Damn right it does. mouseover adds a class. This class has a background image. what's your explanation then?

Comment: `:hover` is a CSS pseudo-selector. Mouseover is the JavaScript event that, in this case, adds a class which contains the background image style.

Comment: These are two paths to the same result.

Comment: Indeed, but they are two different paths, one of which describes how the particular website displays a background image and answers the OP's question. The other describes how the same effect may be achieved elasewhere.